# Python XML parse and count occurence of a string then output to Excel

Tags: python, regex, xml, excel

So here is my conundrum!

I have 100+ XML files that I need to parse and find a string by the tag name(or regular expression).

Once I find that string/tag value I need to count the times it occurs(or find the highest value of that string.)

Example:

```
<content styleCode="Bold">Value 1</content>
<content styleCode="Bold">Value 2</content>
<content styleCode="Bold">Value 3</content>

<content styleCode="Bold">Another Value 1</content>
<content styleCode="Bold">Another Value 2</content>
<content styleCode="Bold">Another Value 3</content>
<content styleCode="Bold">Another Value 4</content>
```

So basically I would want to parse the XML, find the tag listed above and output to an Excel spreadsheet with the highest value found. The spreadsheet already has headers so just the numerical value is output to the Excel file.

So the output would be in Excel:

```
Value    Another Value
3               4
```

The each file would output onto another row.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your XML files were named. 
For the easy case, let's say they were named in this pattern:

file1.xml, file2.xml, ... and they are stored in the same folder as your python script.

Then you can use the following code to do the job:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree
import re
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import Workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

def process():
    for i in xrange(1, 100): #loop from file1.xml to file99.xml
        resultDict = {}
        xml = ElementTree.parse('file%d.xml' %i)
        root = xml.getroot()
        for child in root:
            value = re.search(r'\d+', child.text).group()
            key = child.text[:-(1+len(value))]
            try:
                if value > resultDict[key]:
                    resultDict[key] = value
            except KeyError:
                resultDict[key] = value

        rb = open_workbook("names.xls")
        wb = copy(rb)
        s = wb.get_sheet(0)
        for index, value in enumerate(resultDict.values()):
            s.write(i, index, value)
        wb.save('names.xls')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process()
```

Comment: you might need to install the related packages at [here](http://www.python-excel.org/)

Answer (score 1):

So there are two main parts of the problem. (1) Find the maximum value pair from each file, and (2) Write these in an Excel Workbook. One thing I always advocate is writing reusable code. Here you have to put all your xml files in a folder and simply execute the main method and get the results.

Well now there are several options to write into excel. Simplest one is create a tab or comma separated file **(CSV)** and import it into excel manually. **XMWT** is a standard library. **OpenPyxl** is another library which makes creating excel files much simpler and smaller in terms of lines of code.

Be sure to import required libraries and modules in the beginning of the file.

```
import re
import os
import openpyxl
```

While reading an XML file, we use regular expressions to extract the values you want.

```
regexPatternValue = ">Value\s+(\d+)</content>"
regexPatternAnotherValue = ">Another Value\s+(\d+)</content>"
```

To modularize it a little more, create a method that parses each line in the given XML file, looks for the regex patterns, extracts all the values and returns maximum of them. In the following method, I'm returning a tuple containing two elements, (Value, Another) which are maximum numbers of each type seen in that file.

```
def get_values(filepath):
    values = []
    another = []
    for line in open(filepath).readlines():
        matchValue = re.search(regexPatternValue, line)
        matchAnother = re.search(regexPatternAnotherValue, line)
        if matchValue:
            values.append(int(matchValue.group(1)))
        if matchAnother:
            another.append(int(matchAnother.group(1)))
    # Now we want to calculate highest number in both the lists.
    try:
        maxVal = max(values)
    except:
        maxVal = '' # This case will handle if there are NO values at all
    try:
        maxAnother = max(another)
    except:
        maxAnother = ''
    return maxVal, maxAnother
```

Now keep your XML files in one folder, iterate over them, and extract the regex patterns in each. In the following code, I'm appending these extracted values in a list named as writable_lines. Then finally after parsing all the files, create a Workbook and add the extracted values in the format.

```
def process_folder(folder, output_xls_path):
    files = [folder+'/'+f for f in os.listdir(folder) if ".txt" in f]
    writable_lines = []
    writable_lines.append(("Value","Another Value")) # Header in the excel

    for file in files:
        values = get_values(file)
        writable_lines.append((str(values[0]),str(values[1])))

    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active

    for i in range(len(writable_lines)):
        sheet['A' + str(i+1)].value = writable_lines[i][0]
        sheet['B' + str(i+1)].value = writable_lines[i][1]

    wb.save(output_xls_path)
```

In the lower for-loop, we're directing openpyxl to write the values in the cell specified like typical excel format sheet["A3"], sheet["B3"] etc.

Ready to go...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_folder("xmls", "try.xls")
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Scripts/solution.py", line 41, in <module>
    process_folder("xmls", "try.xls")
  File "C:/Python34/Scripts/solution.py", line 23, in process_folder
    files = [folder+'/'+f for f in os.listdir(folder) if ".txt" in f]
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'xmls' `

Comment: Ah I used a .txt file rather than .xml. Update that first. And second, your folder isn't accessible. Recheck the first argument of process_folder() or try giving full (absolute) folder path.

Comment: In my code, process_folder("xmls", "try.xls") searches for XML files in a FOLDER called "xmls" in your current folder. So there should be a folder like C:/Python34/Scripts/xmls where all your files are stored, or change this folder name in the code.

Comment: Alright, that helped. Now I am getting `File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 7118: character maps to <undefined>.` I believe that decode error is related to the file being in  UTF-8 and I need to add that when the file is opened. I am not sure how to apply that though.

Comment: I'm reading the file in get_values() method. You'll have to fix it there. I hate this issue with python - it has sucked many hours out of my life. However there are wonderful insights to my previous question exactly on this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522015/how-to-solve-this-weird-python-encoding-issue

Comment: Okay a little closer. Now receiving this error `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: There might be some file where there are no Values! So you can use try: maxVal = max(values) , except:  maxVal = []

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I Edited your answer with what I have now.

Comment: Kevin you didn't do what I told in the previous comment. The problem is if there are NO elements in a list, python will throw this ValueError with max() method. I've made edits inside get_values() method definition. Should work.

Comment: @Kevin so here in the except block, you can edit the new lines like maxVal = '' to replace blank to what you want. This will be executed if these Value blocks were not present in the XML.

Comment: Okay, that all makes sense. But no matter what I put in the `regexPatternValue` I can not get it to populate anything in the Excel file.

Comment: Got it working now. How can I make it count if there is not an integer present at the end of the string I am looking for?

Comment: I would like to count the occurrences of the string found via the regular expression not the max value at the end of the string. @aditya jun